# Loading variables from ascii file

Tags: matlab, file, input, io, ascii

I am trying to load variables from a .dat file I have created.

The file is in the following format:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
```

I understand that if the file was in the format:

```
1 2 3
```

I could use

```
s = load(filename.dat)
```

and it would create an array with name 'S' storing all the numbers in the file.

However, from the first format I showed, I would like each stored as a separate variable.

I know I could do this with a .MAT file but this isn't really optimal to my requirements because it needs to be easily edited, preferably with notepad or another word processor.

Answer (score 0):

Try `textread` function:

```
[varNames, varValues] = textread('tmp.txt', '%s%f', 'whitespace','\n', 'delimiter','=');
disp(varNames);
    'x '
    'y '
    'z '

disp(varValues);
     1
     2
     3
```